# Subclass with iboutlet tableview Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a view controller in storyboard with tableview like this:

[image]

It's class is this (I linked the iboutlet tableview called 'tabella'):

```
class RisultatiRicerca: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate{

    var codeSearch = 0

    @IBOutlet public var tabella : UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabella.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        self.tabella.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tabella.delegate = self
        self.tabella.dataSource = self
        self.tabella.reloadData()

    }

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cella = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "risu") as! CellaRisultato

        return cella

    }

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return 10
    }

}
```

My problem is this:

I have to create a subclass of this above, for example this:

```
class TuttiRicerca: RisultatiRicerca {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.codeSearch = 1
    }
}
```

but when I present the `TuttiRicerca` I get this error ('tabella' is nil):

[image]

It's like subclass doesnt link the tableview in the storyboard.
Can you help me?

Comment: You either failed to hook up the outlet in the storyboard or, if you programmatically instantiated this view controller, you did it incorrectly. So, check the outlets in IB. And if you transitioned to this scene programmatically, so us the code you used to do that.

Comment: In the storyboard I have only controller about the 'RisultatiRicerca' class and it's outlet is linked. I havent controller about its subclass

Comment: for istanciate the 'TuttiRicerca' controller I do simply this: public let viewController1 : TuttiRicerca = TuttiRicerca()

Comment: Yep, that's the problem (hence my comment about instantiating it programmatically). You can't just reference `TuttiRicera()`. How does it know which scene in your storyboard you're trying to use (even if you only have one)? You need to give the storyboard scene a "storyboard id" and then instantiate it via the storyboard (e.g. `storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "...")`, not `TuttiRicera()`. See [`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller).

Comment: Yes I understood your question but I wanted to avoid this approach because 
I meant to do so: create a main super class in storyboard with tableview, and create its subclass that has the same tableview (change only the data in tableview for each subclass) and I dont want to create controller in storyboard for each subclass. Can you help me to get this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151801/discussion-between-rob-and-gianni).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `IBOutlet` references, you cannot just reference `TuttiRicera()`. How does it know which scene in your storyboard you're trying to use (even if you only have one)?

You need to give the storyboard scene a "storyboard id" and then instantiate it via the storyboard (e.g. `storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "...")`, not `TuttiRicera()`. See [`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller).

Comment: I did with instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:), but I have a problem: I have the 'RisultatiRicerca' controller in the storyboard and I instantiate it by this method: storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ric"). But I want that it is the 'TuttiRicerca' type, but if I do cast, app crash (of course)

Comment: I do not know if I explained it well but I would try to avoid creating a view controller for each subclass in the storyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151801/discussion-between-rob-and-gianni).